# Displaying plist strings in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, plist

This is similar to my other question, but I was told to make a new question so no one get mad at me.

Ok so basically, I have a UITextView on on view controller, along with a save button. When the save button is tapped, I want the text of the UITextView to be saved to the plist. Then, on a totally separate view controller, I want a UITableView to display the saved files. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance,

Tate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you load and save plist files?

If so, when the button is clicked, do this:

```
[myArray addObject:myTextView.text];  // myArray is an NSMutableArray
```

Then save the array to the plist.  Next show the next view, which contains the table view.  Then the next view can load the plist into another array.

I agree with another poster on your other question that this may not be the best design decision, but I can't see your code so I won't state that as fact.

To expand on this further:

IBAction button touchUp event...add text to array (if any)...save array to plist file...change the current view controller...on the viewDidLoad of the next view controller you load the plist file into another array...then use that array to populate the table view.

Comment: I use this code to save it to a plist.  Is this right?  NSString *typedText = typingArea.text;
 NSMutableArray *totalFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedFiles.plist"];
 
 [totalFiles addObject:typedText];
 
 [totalFiles writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

Comment: [totalFiles writeToFile:path atomically:YES];  what does this method return, YES or NO?